# Clearing Pending Delete State

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

The [`Table<TEntity>.DeleteOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.DATA.LINQ.TABLE%601.DELETEONSUBMIT%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) method has the following description:

`Puts an entity from this table into a pending delete state.`

How can I clear this pending delete state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you're not using any retrieved objects from your context, you should simply be able to set your `DbContext` to `null` and create a new one, that's probably the *cleanest* way to reset your changes.

If you are using retrieved objects and setting it to `null` isn't an option, then you could loop through `db.GetChangeSet().Deletes` and call `.Clear()` on them.

Comment: +1 arguably the easiest thing to do is discard the DataContext before calling SubmitChanges()